# Function for allowing only numeric input not returning false via addEventListener

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

In my external JS-file I have following code to disable non numeric input by user:

```
function numericInput(evt) {
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 48 || charCode < 57)
    {
        return true;
    } 
    else 
    {
       return false;
    }
 }
```

I want to add this function via `addEventListener` and I did the following:

```
document.getElementById("myTextbox").addEventListener("keypress", function (evt) {
    numericInput(evt);
}, false);
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why would it matter what that function returns, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: @adeneo I want to disable user to use non numeric keys, if they type "a" I what that nothing happens in the textbox

Comment: Try replacing `return false` with `evt.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part `charCode > 48 || charCode < 57` in your if-statement, will actually always return true. This is because every number is bigger than 48 or is smaller than 57. I think `||` should have been `&&`. Another thing, the smallest KeyCode for a number is 48, which is not included if you replace `||` with `&&`. The largest KeyCode for a number, 57, isn't neither.

I think your code will work properly if you replace `charCode > 48 || charCode < 57` with `charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57`.

**EDIT:**
As Adeneo mentioned before, you have to replace `return false` with `evt.preventDefault()`.

This function should work:

```js
function numericInput(evt) {
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57)
    {
        return true;
    } 
    else 
    {
       evt.preventDefault();
    }
 }

/*    OR:    */


function numericInput(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) evt.preventDefault();
 }
```